# Delete custom build templates

Tags: tfs, workflow

During development I've created multiple custom build templates, I've added them to the source control. Now that development on the custom build template is done I deleted them from my templates folder in TFS - but they still show in the edit build defintion.

[image: Overview of the workflows]

Does anybody now where TFS stores this information and how I can remove the old ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej,

I've used the following tool for unregistering build process templates:

http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/ - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex to delete the definition from any team projects where you have registered it.

I'm sure there is a way you can do it from the API too, but I don't know it off the top of my head.